# Constructing a joint distribution given $P(X\in A \mid Y)_\omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For random variables $X,Y,Z$, I am given for any measurable set $A$

$$P(X\in A \mid Y)=P(Z\in A\mid Y) \text{ a.s. }\iff (X,Y)\overset{d}{=} (Z,Y).$$

The direction $\Leftarrow$ doesn't seem too hard, but I am not so sure about how to properly show the other direction.

So $P(X\in A\mid Y)_\omega = P(X\in A,Y(\omega))$. Can I "build" the joint distribution $P(X\in A, Y\in B)$ by using the sum $\sum_{\omega:Y(\omega)\in B} P(X\in A, Y(\omega))$? Then this must be the same if I use $Z$ instead of $X$? The obvious problem here is if $\{Y\in B\}$ is an uncountable set though.

Comment: "So $P(X\in A\mid Y)_\omega = P(X\in A,Y(\omega))$" ??

Comment: In Billinglsey, he writes something like $P[(X,Y)\in J \mid X]_\omega = P[(X(\omega),Y)\in J]$. Are these not equivalent and does what I state not follow?

Comment: These are dangerous notations, which are rightfully avoided in every modern textbook on the subject that I know. Billingsley probably means $P((X,Y)\in J\mid X)=Q(X)$ where $Q(x)=P((x,Y)\in J)$ for every $x$ (an identity which is only true if $Y$ is independent of $X$, by the way), and this expanded formulation is much preferable.

Comment: this should change my answer then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $P(X\in A\mid Y) = P(Z\in A\mid Y)$ a.s. we have $E[P(X\in A\mid Y)\cdot 1_{\{Y\in B\}}] = E[P(Z\in A\mid Y)\cdot 1_{\{Y\in B\}}]$. Using the tower property of the conditional expectation and $\sigma(Y)$-measurability of the indicators, you now get the desired result.